# How to get Dropbox users avatar (account photo)

Tags: dropbox-api

Is there any kind of endpoint, or url pattern that we can use to retrieve users avatar (account photo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible... Check the API documentation: [Account Info](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#account-info)